# Freemarker date locale separator

Tags: locale, freemarker, date-formatting

Is it possible in freemarker to retrieve the separator character used in the locale formatting?

Example script:

```
[#setting locale="de"]
[#assign date = .now?date /]
de ${date?string.short}
<br>
[#setting locale="en"]
en ${date?string.short}
```

Prints the following

```
de 22.11.21
en 11/22/21
```

Is it possible to get the period or slash (separator char) from freemarker context? Is there a built in that can return this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. That character is directly in the `SimpleDateFormat` pattern (a `String`) that Java provides for the locale, so as far as I know, there's not even Java API to get that symbol.

Comment: damn, thanks for confirming